# Not getting associated model data for multiple rows and update value cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

Lead.php(Model)

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'LeadEmailDetail' => array(
            'className' => 'LeadEmailDetail',
            'foreignKey' => 'lead_id',
);
```

LeadEmailDetail.php(Model)

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Lead' => array(
            'className' => 'Lead',
            'foreignKey' => 'lead_id'
         ),
         'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'Country',
            'foreignKey' => 'county_id'
         )
);
```

Country.php(model)

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'LeadEmailDetail' => array(
            'className' => 'LeadEmailDetail',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
        )
    );
```

LeadsController.php(Controller.php)

```
public function edit($id = null)
{

        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            $this->Lead->id = $id;
                if ($this->Lead->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->LeadEmailDetail->saveAll($this->request->data);
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your lead has been updated.'), 'flash/error');
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your lead.'), 'flash/error');
        }

        $lead     = $this->Lead->find('first', array(
                                                   'conditions' => array('id' => $id),
                                                   'recursive'  => 2
                                                   ));


        $Country             = $this->Country->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('lead','Country'));

}
```

Leads\View\Leads\edit.ctp

```
pr($lead);

Array
(
    [Lead] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [website] => http://localhost/phpmyadmin
        )

    [LeadEmailDetail] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [lead_id] => 1
                    [county_id] => 101
                    [name] => tyagi                 
                    [email] => main@gmail.com
                    [Country] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 101
                            [name] => INDIA
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [lead_id] => 1
                    [county_id] => 21
                    [name] => Vikass
                    [email] => vikastyagi7@gmail.com
                    [Country] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                            [nicename] => Andorra
                        )

                )

        )
    )

<?php foreach($lead['LeadEmailDetail'] as $key=>$value) : ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->input('LeadEmailDetail.'.$key.'.id', array('type' => 'hidden',));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('LeadEmailDetail.'.$key.'.first_name', array('label' => 'First Name',));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('LeadEmailDetail.'.$key.'.email', array('label' => 'Email',));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('LeadEmailDetail.'.$key.'.country_id', array(
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'options' => $Country,
                         )
                 ); 
                 ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In edit.ctp file not getting Country default value and not update country_id in lead_email_details.

Below part code not working

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('LeadEmailDetail.'.$key.'.country_id', array(
                            'type' => 'select',
                            'options' => $Country,
                             )
                     ); 
                     ?> 
                 ?>
```

After submit edit form country_id field not update in below array-

```
[LeadEmailDetail] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [first_name] => vikas
            [email] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
            [country_id] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: Did you look at the results of `$this->Country->find('list');`? How does your LeadsController know of the Country model - there is no loadModel in your sample code? I think you need `$this->Lead-> LeadEmailDetail-> Country ->find('list');`

Comment: I have alread loadModel in beforeFilter function in controller